# Why border of UILabel is setting after scrolling the tableview?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

I have table view.In this table view i have a custom cell.In cell i have a label which will have a circle around it at runtime.Now i have written some code so make it circle but it does not show circle when table view is loaded first.When i scroll the tableview then it shows circle around the UILabel.

I am using below code.

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cellId="NotificationCell"
    let cell:NotificationCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! NotificationCell

    cell.label_taskCount.layer.cornerRadius =  cell.label_taskCount.frame.size.height/2
    cell.label_taskCount.layer.borderWidth = 1
    cell.label_taskCount.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    cell.label_taskCount.layoutIfNeeded()
    cell.label_taskCount.text = String(indexPath.row)

    return cell
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting corner radius in `layoutSubViews` in `NotificationCell`,

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    self.label_taskCount.layer.cornerRadius = self.label_taskCount.frame.size.height/2
    self.label_taskCount.layer.borderWidth = 1
    self.label_taskCount.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
}
```

Comment: it is a cell of tableview.I have wrote code in cellforrowatindexpath

Comment: Do it in Custom Cell class.